# How to remove duplicate values in string which has delimiters

Tags: java, delimiter, duplicate-data

I have string with value as ||HelpDesk||IT Staff||IT Staff||Admin||Audit||HelpDesk||

I am trying to write code which should remove duplicates and return the unique values retaining the demiliters like this ||HelpDesk||IT Staff||Admin||Audit||

My code is using HashSet to remove duplicates but the problem is it is removing delimiters. How can I retain delimiters by removing duplicate values only.

Below is my code after removing duplicates and adding back delimiters. But not sure if there is easy way of doing this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestDuplicates testDuplicates = new TestDuplicates();
    String bRole = "||HelpDesk||IT Staff||IT Staff||Admin||Audit||HelpDesk||";
    List<String> listWithoutDuplicates = new ArrayList<String>();
    String noDup = "";
    List<String> splittedStringList =
        new ArrayList<String>();
    SplitOperations splitOperations =
        new SplitOperations();
    splittedStringList =
            splitOperations.splitString(bRole);
    for (int i = 0; i < splittedStringList.size(); i++) {

        HashSet<String> listToSet = new HashSet<String>(splittedStringList);

        listWithoutDuplicates = new ArrayList<String>(listToSet);


    }
    for(int i=0;i<listWithoutDuplicates.size();i++){
         noDup = noDup + "||"+listWithoutDuplicates.get(i);
        System.out.println(listWithoutDuplicates.get(i));
    } 
    System.out.println("No Duplicate is::"+ noDup+"||");


}
```

Thanks

Comment: Split the String by `||` (you will need to escape this characters tho, or using `Pattern.quote`). You can get back the delimiter when constructing the String from the elements in the Set.

Comment: May we know What have you tried so far?

Comment: Consider adding the delimiters back after extracting unique elements out from the HashSet.

Comment: Does the order matter? Eg is it OK to remove the first duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `LinkedHashSet` to preserve insertion order. Once you splitted the String by "||" just add the delimiters when constructing back the String.

```
 String s = "||HelpDesk||IT Staff||IT Staff||Admin||Audit||HelpDesk||";
 Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(s.split(Pattern.quote("||"))));
 String noDup = "||";
 for(String st : set) {
     if(st.isEmpty()) continue;
     noDup += st+"||";
 }
```

Or using the new java 8 Stream API :

```
 String noDup = "||"+
     Arrays.stream(s.split(Pattern.quote("||")))
           .distinct()
           .filter(st -> !st.isEmpty()) //we need to remove the empty String produced by the split
           .collect(Collectors.joining("||"))+"||";
```

Both approaches yield the same result (`||HelpDesk||IT Staff||Admin||Audit||`).

Answer (score 0):

```
public String removeDublicate () {
    String str = "||HelpDesk||IT Staff||IT Staff||Admin||Audit||HelpDesk||";
    String split[] = str.split("\\|\\|");

    String newStr = "";

    for (String s : split) {
        if (!s.isEmpty() && !newStr.contains(s)) {
            newStr += "||" + s;
        }
    }

    newStr += "||";

    return newStr;
}
```

Something like that? `str` could be an argument.

**Edit #1**

If you want to get rid of  `&& !newStr.contains(s)` you can use a `HashSet<String>` instead. I think that is overkill however. `.contains(s)` will do the trick when the string is small such as this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, also it will maintain sequence of elements if you want. Note that I have not written code to put delimiters again.

```
public static void main(String s[]){

        String a = "||HelpDesk||IT Staff||IT Staff||Admin||Audit||HelpDesk||";
        a = a.replaceAll("\\|\\|",",");
        String arr[] = a.split(",");
        //linked hash set in case you want to maintain the sequence of elements
        Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));
        set.remove("");
        System.out.println(set);
        //Iterate through the set and put your delimiters here again
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex-based one liner:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\\|[^|]+)(?=.*\\1\\|)", "");
```

This works by replacing every term that is followed by itself somewhere ahead via a look ahead assertion that uses a back reference.

Here's a non-regex java 8 one liner:

```
Arrays.stream(str.substring(1).split("[|]")).distinct().collect(Collectors.joining("|", "|", "|"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Guava lib](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained) it's a one liner:

```
Joiner.on("||").skipNulls(Splitter.on("||").trimResults().split(<target_string>);)
```

Here is my attempt at it:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Seperator {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String bRole = "||HelpDesk||IT Staff||IT Staff||Admin||Audit||HelpDesk||";

    List<String> listWithoutDuplicates = new ArrayList<String>();

    String noDup = "";

    List<String> splittedStringList = new ArrayList<String>();

    splittedStringList = Arrays.asList(bRole.split("\\|\\|"));

    LinkedHashSet<String> listToSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>(splittedStringList);

    noDup = Seperator.join(listToSet, "||");

    System.out.println("No Duplicate is::"+ noDup+"||");
  }

  public static String join(Set<String> set, String sep) {
    String result = null;
    if(set != null) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      Iterator<String> it = set.iterator();
      if(it.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(it.next());
      }
      while(it.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(sep).append(it.next());
      }
      result = sb.toString();
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

LinkedHashSet are mainly used to preserve the order and ofcourse get uniques elements. Joining is pretty standard, but we can use [Google's Guava Library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) also (Joiner):

So, instead of `Seperator.join(listToSet, "||");`

You'll have: `Joiner.on("||").join(listToSet);`